# Verifying a Google Play In-App Billing Signature in .Net - 2048 bit key, PKCS #1 v1.5

Tags: c#, android, digital-signature

It took me some time to figure out how to verify a Google Play In-App Billing signature in ASP.NET so I thought I would share how I did it on StackOverflow.

As described in [Implementing In-app Billing (IAB Version 3)](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html):

> To help ensure the integrity of the transaction information that is
>   sent to your application, Google Play signs the JSON string that
>   contains the response data for a purchase order. Google Play uses the
>   private key that is associated with your application in the Developer
>   Console to create this signature. The Developer Console generates an
>   RSA key pair for each application.
>
> Note:To find the public key portion of this key pair, open your
>   application's details in the Developer Console, then click on Services
>   & APIs, and look at the field titled Your License Key for This
>   Application.
>
> The Base64-encoded RSA public key generated by Google Play is in
>   binary encoded, X.509 subjectPublicKeyInfo DER SEQUENCE format. It is
>   the same public key that is used with Google Play licensing.
>
> When your application receives this signed response you can use the
>   public key portion of your RSA key pair to verify the signature. By
>   performing signature verification you can detect responses that have
>   been tampered with or that have been spoofed. You can perform this
>   signature verification step in your application; however, if your
>   application connects to a secure remote server then we recommend that
>   you perform the signature verification on that server.

I will self-answer this question with the code I wrote to decode the binary encoded, X.509 public key in DER sequence format and use the .Net RSA API's to verify the signature.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Google Play signs the purchase info (which includes your developer payload) with a PKCS #1 version 1.5 signature. To verify the signature you need the signature (signed purchase info), the raw purchase info text and the public key  which is available in the Services & API settings in the Google Play Developer Console.

The public key is encoded in ASN.1 format with DER (which is a subset of BER).

Assuming the purchase info and signature all available as strings that were posted to your web form or MVC controller, and the public key is available in a string loaded from a database or web.config, with the purchase info being raw and the signature and key being Base64 encoded, this code converts them to byte arrays and calls a method to verify the signature:

```
            byte[] purchaseInfoBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(purchaseInfo);
            byte[] signatureBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);
            byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);

            result = CryptUtil.VerifySignature_2048_Bit_PKCS1_v1_5(
                purchaseInfoBytes,
                signatureBytes,
                publicKeyBytes);
```

Here is the code for a simple class that decodes the public key and verifies the signature. The comments inside the class explain how the signature is decoded and include links to helpful articles about [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One), [PKCS #1 version 1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313) and [DER (BER) encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguished_Encoding_Rules#DER_encoding).

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace YourNamespace.Cryptography
{
    public static class CryptUtil
    {
        public static RSAParameters GetRsaParameters_2048_Bit_PKCS1_v1_5(byte[] publicKey)
        {
            // From RFC 2313, PKCS #1, Version 1.5:https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313
            // 7.1 Public-key syntax
            //
            // An RSA public key shall have ASN.1 type RSAPublicKey:
            //
            // RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
            //      modulus INTEGER, -- n
            //      publicExponent INTEGER -- e }
            //
            // (This type is specified in X.509 and is retained here for
            // compatibility.)
            //
            // The fields of type RSAPublicKey have the following meanings:
            //
            // o    modulus is the modulus n.
            //
            // o    publicExponent is the public exponent e.
            //            

            // BER Encoding
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguished_Encoding_Rules#DER_encoding
            //
            // ASN.1 Format with DER (subset of BER) encoding
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One

            // It's important to know that the RSAPublicKey is encoded in an ASN.1 (Abstract Syntax Notation One)
            // representation using DER encoding. I had to use a couple articles on Wikipedia to understand
            // ASN.1 and then I manually decoded the public key to determine where the modulus and exponent were
            // located within the 2048 bit public key from Google.
            //
            // Bytes of sample 2048 bit Public Key (hexadecimal) with ASN.1 decoding shown for each byte
            // 30       Identifier: 30 hex = 00110000, P/C = Constructed (1), TAG = SEQUENCE (10000)
            // 82       Length: 82 hex = 130 decimal = 10000010, Long Form Length with 2 octects for length
            // 01       Byte 1/2 of long form length
            // 22       Byte 2/2 of long form length, 0x01 0x22, 00000001 00100010 = 290 bytes
            // 30       Identifier: 30 hex = 00110000, P/C = Constructed (1), TAG = SEQUENCE (10000)
            // 0d       Length: 0d hex = 13 decimal
            // 06       Identifier: 06 hex = 00000110, P/C = Primitive (0), TAG = OBJECT IDENTIFIER (00110)
            // 09       Length: 09 hex = 9 decimal
            // 2a       Byte 1/9 of OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            // 86       Byte 2/9 of OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            // 48       Byte 3/9 of OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            // 86       Byte 4/9 of OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            // f7       Byte 5/9 of OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            // 0d       Byte 6/9 of OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            // 01       Byte 7/9 of OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            // 01       Byte 8/9 of OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            // 01       Byte 9/9 of OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            // 05       Identifier: 05 hex = 00000101, P/C = Primitive (0), TAG = NULL (00101)
            // 00       Length: 00 hex = 0 decimal
            // 03       Identifier: 03 hex = 00000011, P/C = Primitive (0), TAG = BIT STRING (00011)
            // 82       Length: 82 hex = 130 decimal = 10000010, Long Form Length with 2 octects for length
            // 01       Byte 1/2 of long form length
            // 0f       Byte 2/2 of long form length, 0x01 0x0f, 00000001 00010000 = 272 bytes
            // 00       ???? Why 0, what does this mean?
            // 30       Identifier: 30 hex = 00110000, P/C = Constructed (1), TAG = SEQUENCE (10000)
            // 82       Length: 82 hex = 130 decimal = 10000010, Long Form Length with 2 octects for length
            // 01       Byte 1/2 of long form length        
            // 0a       Byte 2/2 of long form length, 0x01 0x0a, 00000001 00001010 = 266 bytes
            // 02       Identifier: 02 hex = 00000010, P/C = Primitive (0), TAG = INTEGER (00010)
            // 82       Length: 82 hex = 130 decimal = 10000010, Long Form Length with 2 octects for length
            // 01       Byte 1/2 of long form length
            // 01       Byte 2/2 of long form length, 0x01 0x01, 00000001 00000001 = 257 bytes
            // 00       Byte 1/257 of modulus (padded left with a 0, leaves 256 actual values)      
            // a9       Byte 2/257 of modulus... public key (modulus) starts here??
            // 87       Byte 3/257 of modulus
            // ....
            // 8f       Byte 255/257 of modulus
            // 14       Byte 256/257 of modulus93       Byte 257/257 of modulus
            // 02       Identifier: 02 hex = 00000010, P/C = Primitive (0), TAG = INTEGER (00010)
            // 03       Length: 03 hex = 3 decimal
            // 01       Byte 1/3 of exponent
            // 00       Byte 2/3 of exponent
            // 01       Byte 3/3 of exponent

            // Modulus starts at byte offset 33 and is 2048 bits (256 bytes)
            // Exponent starts at byte offset 291 and is 3 bytes

            RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();

            int modulusOffset = 33;     // See comments above
            int modulusBytes = 256;     // 2048 bit key
            int exponentOffset = 291;   // See comments above
            int exponentBytes = 3;      // See comments above

            byte[] modulus = new byte[modulusBytes];
            for (int i = 0; i < modulusBytes; i++)
                modulus[i] = publicKey[modulusOffset + i];

            byte[] exponent = new byte[exponentBytes];
            for (int i = 0; i < exponentBytes; i++)
                exponent[i] = publicKey[exponentOffset + i];

            rsaParameters.Modulus = modulus;
            rsaParameters.Exponent = exponent;

            return rsaParameters;
        }

        public static bool VerifySignature_2048_Bit_PKCS1_v1_5(byte[] data, byte[] signature, byte[] publicKey)
        {
            // Links for information about PKCS #1 version 1.5:
            // RFC 2313: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313
            // PKCS #1 on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1


            // Compute an SHA1 hash of the raw data
            SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);

            // Specify the public key
            RSAParameters rsaParameters = GetRsaParameters_2048_Bit_PKCS1_v1_5(publicKey);

            // Use RSACryptoProvider to verify the signature with the public key
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

            RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter rsaDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);
            rsaDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
            return rsaDeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, signature);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Or if you prefer LINQ:
new RSAParameters {
    Modulus = publicKey.Skip(33).Take(256).ToArray(),
    Exponent = publicKey.Skip(291).Take(3).ToArray()
}